# svn causes build errors in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I imported a java project into eclipse which had .svn folders in it. The project did on build properly and it gave errors. But, once I deleted the .svn folders from the project, eclipse did not show any errors. What is the reason ?

Comment: Come on, help us out here. What were the errors? Do you have one of the Eclipse SVN plugins installed? Did you use Eclipse or an external tool to check out the project?

Comment: If you have the Eclipse SVN plugin installed then most likely your .project and/or .classpath files are incorrect.  If not then I would start with the plugin.

Comment: I do not have any svn plugins installed.

Comment: cleaning the project resolved build errors. Can anyone explain why it worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, as pointed out in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg21026.html), you need to add .svn to the list of things you don't want copied to the output folder.

```
Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Building->Output folder
```

> Indeed, when I added added "`.svn`" to the list of "Filtered Resources", the problem went away.
>   I had two source directories: `src` and `test`, which both were in SVN.
>   Apparently Eclipse realized that `src/.svn/entries` and `test/.svn/entries` are duplicates and it complained.